# Should we drop the use of "christian" as a qualifier in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Can I rename "christian-dash-something" tags to drop the qualifier?

For example we have [christian-parenting](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian-parenting), but it seems to me on this site that the Christian part is a given and that just [parenting](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting) would suffice.

To put this another way, does anybody plan on asking questions and tagging them [pagan-parenting](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagan-parenting)? Or is there another argument for having the extra qualifier attached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes please.

"Christian" in a tag in nearly any tag is as redundant as the [christian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christian) and [chritianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chritianity) tags were.

Comment: Please note that if there are a ridiculous number of posts using a christian-something tag ("ridiculous number" for these purposes meaning that all the edits would flood the front page if you changed them manually), you can just make a meta post about it and someone with a diamond will merge it into the better tag.

Comment: @HedgeMage: Thanks for  info. There were only 8 or so and I already took care of  them already but I will keep that in mind for the future.